# Is there a generalization of Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity for cubic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was wondering if there was a cubic version of [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) .

I looked everywhere but I didn't find anything ,except the splendid website of Tito Piezas (see [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/010))
Furthermore I know the Gauss identity wich is :
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

So my question is :
Is there a generalization of Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity or Gauss identity ?

Thanks a lot .

Comment: As you say, Tito's page is so splendid, that every such generalisation would already be there. So have a look again. I did not find a cubic Bramagupta yet.

Comment: Do you mean something like $(a^3+b^3)(c^3+d^3)=f(a,b,c,d)^3+ g(a,b,c,d)^3$ where  $f$ and $g$ are some integer polynomial? Or something else?

Comment: @Robert Z Yes I mean something like that , furthermore I just find [this](http://jrms.ramanujanmathsociety.org/in-publication/in-publication-list/a-cubic-generalization-of-brahmagupta-s-identity) but there is nothing...

Comment: In order to have a cubic version of the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity, you need to have a "cubic semigroup" like $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ or something analogous, don't you?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653086/on-the-cubic-generalization-a3b3c3d3e3f3g3h3-v-13v-23v) may be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not one.

If there were one, that would mean that the set of the sums of two integer cubes is closed under multiplication. However,

$$(1^3+1^3)(1^3+1^3)=4,$$

which is not the sum of two integer cubes (positive, negative, or zero).

Comment: +1 Simple but powerful (generalises to all higher powers).

Comment: @AdamBailey Thank you, and that's a good point!

Answer (score 1):

There is, provided your are prepared to have 3 letters in the identity. It requires consideration of multiplication in a cubic field. See http://www.mathjournals.org/jrms/2017-032-004/2017-032-004-001.html

Let $$N_j = \left ( \begin {array} {ccc} u_j & -a d y_j & -a d x_j - b d y_j \\ x_j & u_j - b x_j -c y_j & - c x_j - d y_j \\ y_j & a x_j & u_j - c y_j  \\\end {array} \right) .$$ Then define $$N_1 N_2 = N_3. $$ Taking determinants gives such an identity.